# String comparison in Perl seems invalid

Tags: perl

I have following bunch of code:

```
my $f1 = $ARGV[0] // '';
my $f2 = $ARGV[1] // '';
print "f1: $f1\n";
print "f2: $f2\n";
if ($f2 eq '') {
    print "reach here\n";
    open(DATA1, $f1) or die $!;
} else {
    open(DATA1, $f2) or die $!;
}
```

it will receive 1 or 2 arguments from command-line, the command line call would look like this:

```
perl perl_unix_wc.pl -l file.txt
```

or this:

```
perl perl_unix_wc.pl file.txt
```

I tried to define 2 scalars to receive the string from command line, if it applies to case 1, then the 
'open(DATA1, $f2) or die $!' will got called, otherwise 'open(DATA1, $f1) or die $!' will got called. But in practice, only case 2 is executed, case 1 never reached. What is wrong with my code here? Is it something wrong with the string comparison here? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to enter the first argument OR '' in the f1 and second argument OR '' in f2?  Should you try || instead of // ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears that you don't need `-l`, just `pop` the last (or only) element off of `@ARGV`, since in either case, it'll be the file name:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV or die "No arguments passed to $0!\n";

my $file = pop;
open my $DATA1, '<', $file or die "Unable to open $file: $!";

...
```

However, if you're only going to pass the file name, you can do the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<>){
    # process the file's lines
}
```

Comment: I think my solution kind of works since when I just pass 1 parameter, the 'reach here' will be printed, but seems the file is not opened(the file is there and in the same directory).

Comment: @photosynthesis - If you're only going to pass the file name, let Perl handle the file i/o.  See the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Getopt%3A%3ALong&mode=all) to process the command line options.

```
use Getopt::Long; # GetOptions

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

GetOptions(
    'l' => \my $opt_l,
);

my $file = shift or die "Filename required";

open my $fh, '<', $file;

if ($opt_l) {
     print "do -l stuff\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@ARGV would return the no. of arguments passed... if @ARGV == 1 then execute case 1 or if @ARGV == 2 execute case2

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
my $f1 = $ARGV[0] ;
my $f2 = $ARGV[1] ;
print "f1: $f1\n";
print "f2: $f2\n";
if (@ARGV == 1) {
    open(DATA1, $f1) or die $!;
} elsif (@ARGV == 2) {
    open(DATA1, $f2) or die $!;
}
```

If you want to stick to your coding style.. try

```
my $f1 = $ARGV[0] || '';
my $f2 = $ARGV[1] || '';
print "f1: $f1\n";
print "f2: $f2\n";
if ($f2 eq '') {
    open(DATA1, $f1) or die $!;
} else {
    open(DATA1, $f2) or die $!;
}
```